# Computing date difference from within DevExpress

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, devexpress, datediff

We use a third-party software that uses DevExpress for building reports. Normally on Oracle - I can get the difference in dates with ease by simply subtracting them:

```sql
TRUNC(sysdate) - TRUNC(a.birth_date) AS datediff
```

I used the same logic from within DevExpress:

```sql
CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS VARCHAR(9)) AS DATE) - CAST(CAST(a.birth_date AS VARCHAR(9)) AS DATE) AS datediff
```

But doing so gives me this error message:

> Invalid cast from 'Decimal' to 'DateTime'. Couldn't store <35> in DATEDIFF Column.
>   Expected type is DateTime.

How do I fix this?

---

**Notes:**

- There's a lot of casting going on here but that's just a work-around because `TRUNC` doesn't work so I'm basically just casting to a `VARCHAR` essentially removing the time portion and casting it back to a `DATE` field.
- `CURRENT_DATE` is the equivalent of `SYSDATE` in the world of DevExpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the simplest solution is to cast the result to `decimal`.

```sql
CAST(CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS VARCHAR(9)) AS DATE) - CAST(CAST(a.birth_date AS VARCHAR(9)) AS DATE) AS DECIMAL) AS datediff
```